# formulating an idiomatic multiple-choice question

Tags: phrase-request

Is it idiomatic to say "What is a toy from the East?" (meaning "Which toy comes from the East?") in a multiple choice quiz? For example:

> What is a toy from the East?
>
> 1. top
> 2. butterfly
> 3. blocks

Or will it sound a bit off?

Comment: It will sound off -  **which is a toy from the East?** is the grammatically correct choice (select one from a list).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A) What is a toy from the East? [Grammar FINE, meaning, NOT FINE, for the multiple choice given.

- A top
- A butterfly
- Blocks

To answer A), you have to say something like: A toy from the East is Oriental.

- What is a toy from the East?

**It is**:

- Oriental
- Asian
- Indonesian
- None of the above
- Very cute
- A top, a butterfly, blocks [all unlikely but grammatically possible].

B) Which one (or Which [of these]) is a toy from the East? [Grammar, FINE. Meaning: Asks for the object to be pointed out by a person. This one or that one or A top, A butterfly or Blocks.

**This one or that one or x is/are a toy from the East**.

- A top
- A butterfly
- Blocks

To answer B), you have to point out or identify which options work for a toy from the East by ticking a box or pointing to it. It is not about identifying the nature of the object as What is does.

Asking what is/what are is not exactly the same as Which is/are or Which one is/Which one are.

Conclusion: "What is/are" questions are not the same as "Which one/Which is/are" questions.

Answer (score 3):

> Which toy is from the East?

or

> Which is a toy from the East?

The former implies all options are toys, the latter suggests there might be different sorts of things with a toy among them.

*Which* is preferable over *what* when there is a fixed set of options.